# Error: qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found

Tags: bash, docker, qt, dockerfile, xcb

I am attempting to build a Dockerfile to run the software PyReconstruct. I understand I need to forward a display

```
FROM python:3.9.16-bullseye

# Install conda
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl && \
    curl -o /tmp/miniconda.sh https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh && \
    bash /tmp/miniconda.sh -b -p /opt/conda && \
    rm /tmp/miniconda.sh && \
    echo ". /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bashrc && \
    echo "conda activate base" >> ~/.bashrc

ENV PATH /opt/conda/bin:$PATH

# Install system dependency
RUN conda install -c anaconda libxcb -y

# Clone repository and install required dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && git clone https://github.com/SynapseWeb/pyReconstruct pyReconstruct \
    && cd pyReconstruct \
    && pip install --upgrade pip \
    && pip install -r src/requirements.txt

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libgl1 -y \
    && apt-get install -y libxkbcommon-x11-0 \
    && apt-get install libegl1-mesa libegl1 -y \
    && apt-get install libdbus-1-3 -y \
    && apt-get install -y libxcb-xinerama0 \
    && apt-get install -y libxcb-xv0 \
    && apt-get install -y libxcb-util1 \
    && apt-get install -y libxcb-randr0-dev libxcb-xtest0-dev libxcb-xinerama0-dev libxcb-shape0-dev libxcb-xkb-dev \
    && apt-get install -y libxcb-icccm4 \
    && apt-get install -y libxcb-image0 \
    && apt-get install -y libxcb-keysyms1 \
    && apt-get install -y libxcb-render-util0 \
    && apt-get install -y libxcb-shape0 \
    && apt-get install '^libxcb.*-dev' libx11-xcb-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libxrender-dev libxi-dev libxkbcommon-dev libxkbcommon-x11-dev -y \
    && apt-get install python3-pyqt5 -y

# Designate plugin path
ENV QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms

# Navigate to the directory and run the software
RUN cd pyReconstruct \
    && python src/PyReconstruct.py
```

I get the following error:

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: wayland-egl, vkkhrdisplay, linuxfb, minimal, wayland, minimalegl, xcb, eglfs, offscreen, vnc.
```

I have tried the solutions listed online, as you can see from my installations, but others are not relevant for a Dockerfile. I've had no success and I have been held up on this issue for a week. I am not sure if the display is the issue or just the xcb plugin. If anyone has any ideas over how to resolve this issue I would deeply appreciate it!

This software runs in an HPC environment and locally with no issues by simply:

```
git clone https://github.com/SynapseWeb/pyReconstruct $WORK/PyReconstruct

echo "Changing directory to pyReconstruct..."
cd $WORK/PyReconstruct

echo "Fetching updated version of repository..."
git fetch --all && git reset --hard origin/main
git pull

echo "Installing PyReconstruct dependencies..."
pip install -r src/requirements.txt
python src/PyReconstruct.py
```

I am quite new to systems and this software, so any instruction or direction would really help and be deeply appreciated!

I've tried turning the qt debugging on, and that helped to find each dependency I needed. I also tried using a different display, namely wayland, and received the same errors. Here is the current output:

```
export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1
```

```
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: checking directory path "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms" ...                                
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: looking at "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-egl.so"                              
qt.core.plugin.loader: Found metadata in lib /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-egl.so, metadata=                 
{                                                                               
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",    
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland-egl"
        ]
    },
    "archlevel": 1,
    "className": "QWaylandEglPlatformIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 394240
}


qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: Got keys from plugin meta data QList("wayland-egl")
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: looking at "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqvkkhrdisplay.so"
qt.core.plugin.loader: Found metadata in lib /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqvkkhrdisplay.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "vkkhrdisplay"
        ]
    },
    "archlevel": 1,
    "className": "QVkKhrDisplayIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 394240
}


qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: Got keys from plugin meta data QList("vkkhrdisplay")
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: looking at "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so"
qt.core.plugin.loader: Found metadata in lib /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "linuxfb"
        ]
    },
    "archlevel": 1,
    "className": "QLinuxFbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 394240
}


qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: Got keys from plugin meta data QList("linuxfb")
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: looking at "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so"
qt.core.plugin.loader: Found metadata in lib /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimal"
        ]
    },
    "archlevel": 1,
    "className": "QMinimalIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 394240
}


qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: Got keys from plugin meta data QList("minimal")
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: looking at "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-generic.so"
qt.core.plugin.loader: Found metadata in lib /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-generic.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland"
        ]
    },
    "archlevel": 1,
    "className": "QWaylandIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 394240
}


qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: Got keys from plugin meta data QList("wayland")
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: looking at "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so"
qt.core.plugin.loader: Found metadata in lib /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimalegl"
        ]
    },
    "archlevel": 1,
    "className": "QMinimalEglIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 394240
}


qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: Got keys from plugin meta data QList("minimalegl")
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: looking at "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
qt.core.plugin.loader: Found metadata in lib /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb"
        ]
    },
    "archlevel": 1,
    "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 394240
}


qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: Got keys from plugin meta data QList("xcb")
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: looking at "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so"
qt.core.plugin.loader: Found metadata in lib /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "eglfs"
        ]
    },
    "archlevel": 1,
    "className": "QEglFSIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 394240
}


qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: Got keys from plugin meta data QList("eglfs")
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: looking at "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so"
qt.core.plugin.loader: Found metadata in lib /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "offscreen"
        ]
    },
    "archlevel": 1,
    "className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 394240
}


qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: Got keys from plugin meta data QList("offscreen")
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: looking at "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so"
qt.core.plugin.loader: Found metadata in lib /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "vnc"
        ]
    },
    "archlevel": 1,
    "className": "QVncIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 394240
}


qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: Got keys from plugin meta data QList("vnc")
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: checking directory path "/opt/conda/bin/platforms" ...
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: checking directory path "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins" ...
qt.core.library: "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so" loaded library
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display docker.for.mac.host.internal:0
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: wayland-egl, vkkhrdisplay, linuxfb, minimal, wayland, minimalegl, xcb, eglfs, offscreen, vnc.

Aborted (core dumped)
root@6d1f827721e2:/# python pyReconstruct/src/PyReconstruct.py 
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: checking directory path "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms" ...
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: looking at "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-egl.so"
qt.core.plugin.loader: Found metadata in lib /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-egl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland-egl"
        ]
    },
    "archlevel": 1,
    "className": "QWaylandEglPlatformIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 394240
}


qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: Got keys from plugin meta data QList("wayland-egl")
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: looking at "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqvkkhrdisplay.so"
qt.core.plugin.loader: Found metadata in lib /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqvkkhrdisplay.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "vkkhrdisplay"
        ]
    },
    "archlevel": 1,
    "className": "QVkKhrDisplayIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 394240
}


qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: Got keys from plugin meta data QList("vkkhrdisplay")
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: looking at "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so"
qt.core.plugin.loader: Found metadata in lib /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "linuxfb"
        ]
    },
    "archlevel": 1,
    "className": "QLinuxFbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 394240
}


qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: Got keys from plugin meta data QList("linuxfb")
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: looking at "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so"
qt.core.plugin.loader: Found metadata in lib /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimal"
        ]
    },
    "archlevel": 1,
    "className": "QMinimalIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 394240
}


qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: Got keys from plugin meta data QList("minimal")
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: looking at "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-generic.so"
qt.core.plugin.loader: Found metadata in lib /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-generic.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland"
        ]
    },
    "archlevel": 1,
    "className": "QWaylandIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 394240
}


qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: Got keys from plugin meta data QList("wayland")
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: looking at "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so"
qt.core.plugin.loader: Found metadata in lib /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimalegl"
        ]
    },
    "archlevel": 1,
    "className": "QMinimalEglIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 394240
}


qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: Got keys from plugin meta data QList("minimalegl")
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: looking at "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
qt.core.plugin.loader: Found metadata in lib /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb"
        ]
    },
    "archlevel": 1,
    "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 394240
}


qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: Got keys from plugin meta data QList("xcb")
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: looking at "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so"
qt.core.plugin.loader: Found metadata in lib /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "eglfs"
        ]
    },
    "archlevel": 1,
    "className": "QEglFSIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 394240
}


qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: Got keys from plugin meta data QList("eglfs")
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: looking at "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so"
qt.core.plugin.loader: Found metadata in lib /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "offscreen"
        ]
    },
    "archlevel": 1,
    "className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 394240
}


qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: Got keys from plugin meta data QList("offscreen")
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: looking at "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so"
qt.core.plugin.loader: Found metadata in lib /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "vnc"
        ]
    },
    "archlevel": 1,
    "className": "QVncIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 394240
}


qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: Got keys from plugin meta data QList("vnc")
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: checking directory path "/opt/conda/bin/platforms" ...
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: checking directory path "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins" ...
qt.core.library: "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so" loaded library
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display docker.for.mac.host.internal:0
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: wayland-egl, vkkhrdisplay, linuxfb, minimal, wayland, minimalegl, xcb, eglfs, offscreen, vnc.
```

Maybe something here can be of help!